# handling sticky bread dough

Tags: bread

What is the best way to handle sticky "batard dough" to shape it before putting it in the oven? I have tried flouring my hands and the crust comes out too white. I have tried using cooking utensils and find that I cannot shape it properly.

Comment: What hydration are we talking about? So how have you been shaping so far and are you using a “couche” (linnen cloth) for the final raise?

Answer (score 4):

For really wet dough, wetting your hands works (that is, quickly dip them in a bowl of water, let the water drip off a little, and keep doing that as you work the dough). Depending on the dough, you could also oil your hands (see the "[Is there a reason to NOT use no-stick spray (Pam) for handling dough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/44041/is-there-a-reason-to-not-use-no-stick-spray-pam-for-handling-dough)" over to the right in related questions). Also helps to be quick; keep your hands moving and the dough sticks less.

And to some extent, you just have to live with it being a sticky mess.

Comment: Wetting hands is what I do. Using spray oil is just a mess.